# Validate integers

Tags: validation, integer

I would like to create a php file  to echo  'valid' or 'invalid' to a text input. The text is a series of four numbers separated by space eg 2 9 15 18
.The text will be validated upon the following constraints:

1. The series must contain four numbers seperated.
2. Each number should be between 1 and 20.
3. Any other diviation should produce an invalid response for example :

0 1 3 12  = invalid
  one number out of range. ie zero .
4 11 13 26 = invalid 
 one number out of range. ie twenty six.
A 1 15 18 = invalid 
 a letter in the series.
5 11 18 = invalid 
three integers in the series
2 9 10 15 18 = invalid
too many integers is the series

Comment: And what difficulty are you having with doing this?  You've stated a task but not asked a question.

Comment: I am new to php , i need someone to point me out on the right direction. What php functions to use

Comment: RegEx migth come in handy as well. Check the php RegEx documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a piece of code that you can have a look at. 
The essentials are `is_int`, `intval` and `explode`. As of now it just return true or false,
but you can print appropriate messages according to the checks if you like.

```
function validNumber($num) {
    return is_int($num) && $num > 0 && $num <= 20;
}

function validNumbers($string) {
    $numbers = explode(" ",$string);
    if(count($numbers) != 4) return false;
    //check for unique values
    if(count($numbers) != count(array_unique($numbers))) return false;
    foreach($numbers as $number)
        if(!validNumber(intval($number))) return false;
    return true;
}

printf("<pre>%b</pre>", validNumbers("0 1 3 12")); // false
printf("<pre>%b</pre>", validNumbers("1 3 12")); // false
printf("<pre>%b</pre>", validNumbers("A 2 3 12")); // false
printf("<pre>%b</pre>", validNumbers("5 1 3 12")); // true
```

Example with valid/invalid as output:

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", validNumbers("5 1 3 12") ? "valid" : "invalid");
```

Comment: i am getting when i run your function <pre>0</pre>

Comment: 1 = true, 0 = false. Updated with one more example.

Comment: can i then use an IF ELSE statement for
example: 

$txt = 3 7 11 15; $result = printf("<pre>%s</pre>",
validNumbers("$txt") ? "valid" : "invalid"); 
if $result = valid, { echo " the numbers are correct
"} ; else ,{ echo "incorrect numbers
submitted"};

Comment: Thank you for the code. It works perfect but I had forgot one more rule: each number must be different from the rest  for example numbers 5 6 11 5 is valid as the code stands. it should be invalid since 5 is repeated

Comment: the followimg is returning a valid response : 3a 11 15 18